# Filtering Ajax loaded table

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, html-table

I'm trying to filter a table with Javascript. The code I'm using is the following:

```
var $rows = $('tr').not('#tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {

    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text);
    }).hide();
});
```

it works fine with a static table like this one:

```
<table id="table">
   <tr id="tr">
      <th><h4>uuid</h4></th>
      <th><h4>xValue</h4></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><p>stuff2</p></td>
       <td><p>foo2</p></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td><p>stuff</p></td>
       <td><p>foo</p></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

but when I create the table dynamically from a json with ajax, the filtering script is not working anymore. How can I solve this?

Here's the code for table generation from json I use:

```
var url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos';

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        drawTable(data);
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log(e.message);
    }
});

function drawTable(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        drawRow(data[i]);
    }
}

function drawRow(rowData) {
    var row = $('<tr/>')
    $("#table").append(row); //this will append tr element to table... keep its reference for a while since we will add cels into it
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.id + "</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.name + "</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.lastName + "</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.private + "</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.fork + "</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.description + "</p></td>"));
    row.append($("<td><p>" + rowData.size + "</p></td>"));
}
```

Comment: did u get any error, or what result u got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your defining `$rows` before your search function. Adding new rows dynamically after its been set wont change the value of `$rows`.  Try defining it within the search function

```
$('#search').keyup(function() {
  var $rows = $('tr').not('#tr'); // set value here
  ..
```